# FFmpeg smearing rtp missed packet

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rtsp, rtmp

I'm using ffmpeg to combine streams. But during the combinaison I have some errors/Warnings. I don't know why. I can see the frames are dropping. And the output video is poor quality

Here the situation : 
First : Try to combine local video and a rtsp stream from data center.

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://cloudzensg.loginto.me:554/livecast -i Xmen2trailer.mov -filter_complex "[0]scale=-1:-1[b];[1]scale=128:128[w];[b][w] overlay=10:10" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -f flv out.mp4
ffmpeg version N-89672-g41e51fbcd9 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
[udp @ 000001e07f58ccc0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 000001e07f5a2b80] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 000001e07f5b4040] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 000001e07f5c4300] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://cloudzensg.loginto.me:554/livecast':
  Metadata:
    title           : session
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.086367, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Xmen2trailer.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2003-02-17T16:23:00.000000Z
    title           : X2
    title-eng       : X2
    copyright-eng   : ┬⌐2003 20th Century Fox
    comment         : QuickTime 5 version encoded and delivered by www.apple.com/trailers/
    copyright       : ┬⌐2003 20th Century Fox
    comment-eng     : QuickTime 5 version encoded and delivered by www.apple.com/trailers/
  Duration: 00:02:29.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1283 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: svq3 (SVQ3 / 0x33515653), yuvj420p(pc), 480x272, 1153 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2003-02-17T16:23:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Sorenson Video 3
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: qdm2 (QDM2 / 0x324D4451), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2003-02-17T16:23:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (svq3) -> scale (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #1:1 -> #0:1 (qdm2 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 000001e002b3d980] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 000001e07f5edd00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001e07f5edd00] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 000001e07f5edd00] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, flv, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : session
    encoder         : Lavf58.3.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.9.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2003-02-17T16:23:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.9.100 libmp3lame
Past duration 0.889320 too large
Past duration 0.629326 too large
Past duration 0.979652 too large
Past duration 0.909660 too large
Past duration 0.646996 too large
Past duration 0.881325 too large
Past duration 0.728661 too large
Past duration 0.970665 too large
Past duration 0.610664 too large
Past duration 0.851997 too large
Past duration 0.779991 too large
Past duration 0.870995 too large
Past duration 0.752327 too large
Past duration 0.970665 too large
Past duration 0.679665 too large
Past duration 0.951988 too large
Past duration 0.913994 too large
Past duration 0.641655 too large
[rtsp @ 000001e07f58a700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000001e07f58a700] RTP: missed 747 packets
[h264 @ 000001e07f63a140] corrupted macroblock 30 15 (total_coeff=-1)063.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=66 speed=6.52x
[h264 @ 000001e07f63a140] error while decoding MB 30 15
[h264 @ 000001e07f63a140] concealing 2380 DC, 2380 AC, 2380 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.971657 too large
Past duration 0.867989 too large    1280kB time=00:00:04.44 bitrate=2360.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=70 speed=1.44x
[rtsp @ 000001e07f58a700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000001e07f58a700] RTP: missed 43 packets
[h264 @ 000001e07f639380] corrupted macroblock 11 18 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 000001e07f639380] error while decoding MB 11 18
[h264 @ 000001e07f639380] concealing 2156 DC, 2156 AC, 2156 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.895988 too large
Past duration 0.708656 too large
frame=  105 fps= 29 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2169kB time=00:00:08.98 bitrate=1977.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=76 speed=2.52x
video:2020kB audio:141kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.363079%
[libx264 @ 000001e07f5edd00] frame I:1     Avg QP:20.00  size: 84510
[libx264 @ 000001e07f5edd00] frame P:104   Avg QP:18.44  size: 19074
[libx264 @ 000001e07f5edd00] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001e07f5edd00] mb P  I16..4: 15.4%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 23.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:61.5%
[libx264 @ 000001e07f5edd00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 7.4% 7.3% 4.5% inter: 14.3% 12.2% 3.4%
[libx264 @ 000001e07f5edd00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 71% 27%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 000001e07f5edd00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 58% 37%  4%  0%
[libx264 @ 000001e07f5edd00] kb/s:1969.74
Exiting normally, received signal 2
```

second :
Try to combine local rtsp and local video

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.203:554/livecast -i Xmen2trailer.mov -filter_complex "[0]scale=-1:-1[b];[1]scale=128:128[w];[b][w] overlay=10:10" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -f flv out.mp4
ffmpeg version N-89672-g41e51fbcd9 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
[udp @ 000002aa1fe4ca00] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 000002aa1fe62900] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 000002aa1fe73d80] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 000002aa1fe84040] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://192.168.1.203:554/livecast':
  Metadata:
    title           : session
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Xmen2trailer.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2003-02-17T16:23:00.000000Z
    title           : X2
    title-eng       : X2
    copyright-eng   : ┬⌐2003 20th Century Fox
    comment         : QuickTime 5 version encoded and delivered by www.apple.com/trailers/
    copyright       : ┬⌐2003 20th Century Fox
    comment-eng     : QuickTime 5 version encoded and delivered by www.apple.com/trailers/
  Duration: 00:02:29.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1283 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: svq3 (SVQ3 / 0x33515653), yuvj420p(pc), 480x272, 1153 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2003-02-17T16:23:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Sorenson Video 3
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: qdm2 (QDM2 / 0x324D4451), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2003-02-17T16:23:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (svq3) -> scale (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 000002aa2355ba40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 000002aa202d9600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000002aa202d9600] profile Constrained Baseline, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 000002aa202d9600] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, flv, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : session
    encoder         : Lavf58.3.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.9.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.9.100 libmp3lame
Past duration 0.711662 too large
Past duration 0.822990 too large
Past duration 0.854332 too large
[rtsp @ 000002aa1fe4a680] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000002aa1fe4a680] RTP: missed 1315 packets
[h264 @ 000002aa20262580] Invalid level prefix
[h264 @ 000002aa20262580] error while decoding MB 12 37
[h264 @ 000002aa20262580] concealing 3757 DC, 3757 AC, 3757 MV errors in I frame
Past duration 0.732323 too large     256kB time=00:00:02.88 bitrate= 727.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=13 speed=5.76x
Past duration 0.824333 too large
Past duration 0.988991 too large
Past duration 0.862328 too large    1024kB time=00:00:03.38 bitrate=2477.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=21 speed=3.34x
Past duration 0.861320 too large
Past duration 0.883324 too large
Past duration 0.910652 too large    1280kB time=00:00:03.94 bitrate=2659.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=30 speed=2.59x
Past duration 0.954659 too large
Past duration 0.790657 too large    1792kB time=00:00:04.40 bitrate=3335.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=37 speed=2.17x
Past duration 0.861320 too large
Past duration 0.943657 too large
Past duration 0.988655 too large    2304kB time=00:00:04.90 bitrate=3849.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=45 speed=1.94x
Past duration 0.810326 too large
Past duration 0.893654 too large
Past duration 0.822319 too large    3072kB time=00:00:05.40 bitrate=4655.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=53 speed=1.78x
Past duration 0.902657 too large
Past duration 0.909660 too large
Past duration 0.779655 too large    3328kB time=00:00:05.93 bitrate=4596.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=61 speed=1.67x
Past duration 0.957664 too large
Past duration 0.778328 too large    3840kB time=00:00:06.43 bitrate=4890.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=68 speed=1.59x
Past duration 0.861992 too large
Past duration 0.992653 too large
Past duration 0.729652 too large    4352kB time=00:00:06.94 bitrate=5133.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=76 speed=1.53x
[rtsp @ 000002aa1fe4a680] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000002aa1fe4a680] RTP: missed 2 packets
Past duration 0.857994 too large
[h264 @ 000002aa20260580] Invalid level prefix
[h264 @ 000002aa20260580] error while decoding MB 43 62
[h264 @ 000002aa20260580] concealing 726 DC, 726 AC, 726 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.889000 too large
Past duration 0.800987 too large    4864kB time=00:00:07.42 bitrate=5365.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=83 speed=1.47x
Past duration 0.909660 too large
Past duration 0.946327 too large
Past duration 0.795998 too large
Past duration 0.902321 too large    5376kB time=00:00:07.95 bitrate=5539.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=91 speed=1.43x
Past duration 0.841652 too large
Past duration 0.859657 too large
Past duration 0.992332 too large    5632kB time=00:00:08.43 bitrate=5472.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=99 speed=1.39x
Past duration 0.893990 too large
Past duration 0.947990 too large    6400kB time=00:00:08.95 bitrate=5853.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=106 speed=1.36x
Past duration 0.678322 too large
Past duration 0.994987 too large
Past duration 0.942329 too large
Past duration 0.975319 too large
Past duration 0.702660 too large    6912kB time=00:00:09.45 bitrate=5986.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=114 speed=1.34x
Past duration 0.821663 too large
Past duration 0.937325 too large
Past duration 0.992989 too large
Past duration 0.684990 too large    7168kB time=00:00:09.96 bitrate=5895.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=122 speed=1.31x
Past duration 0.763664 too large
Past duration 0.990318 too large
Past duration 0.921333 too large
Past duration 0.945320 too large
Past duration 0.711327 too large    7680kB time=00:00:10.49 bitrate=5994.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=130 speed=1.29x
Past duration 0.841652 too large
Past duration 0.948997 too large
Past duration 0.994652 too large
Past duration 0.759987 too large    8448kB time=00:00:11.04 bitrate=6267.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=138 speed=1.28x
Past duration 0.860985 too large
Past duration 0.984993 too large
Past duration 0.796989 too large    8960kB time=00:00:11.50 bitrate=6382.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=145 speed=1.26x
Past duration 0.914665 too large
Past duration 0.804329 too large    9472kB time=00:00:12.02 bitrate=6452.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=152 speed=1.25x
frame=  303 fps= 31 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10246kB time=00:00:12.33 bitrate=6803.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=156 speed=1.25x
video:10039kB audio:193kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.140463%
[libx264 @ 000002aa202d9600] frame I:2     Avg QP:18.00  size:199681
[libx264 @ 000002aa202d9600] frame P:301   Avg QP:18.96  size: 32823
[libx264 @ 000002aa202d9600] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 000002aa202d9600] mb P  I16..4:  9.3%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 32.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:58.6%
[libx264 @ 000002aa202d9600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 12.9% 34.0% 11.0% inter: 12.0% 22.7% 6.2%
[libx264 @ 000002aa202d9600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 38% 49%  9%  4%
[libx264 @ 000002aa202d9600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 38% 42% 14%  6%
[libx264 @ 000002aa202d9600] kb/s:6833.78
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

third :
Combine RTMP from phone and RTSP video from server

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.203:554/livecast -i rtmp://192.168.1.152:1935/ingest/test -filter_complex "[0]scale=-1:-1[b];[1]scale=200:200[w];[b][w] overlay=10:10" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -f flv outputRTMP.mp4
ffmpeg version N-89672-g41e51fbcd9 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-amf --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  8.100 /  7.  8.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
[udp @ 0000018c0ccbca40] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000018c0ccd2900] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000018c0cce3dc0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000018c0ccf4080] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://192.168.1.203:554/livecast':
  Metadata:
    title           : session
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
Input #1, flv, from 'rtmp://192.168.1.152:1935/ingest/test':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 640
    displayHeight   : 480
    fps             : 0
    profile         :
    level           :
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 173.197000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 47 kb/s
    Stream #1:1: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 640x480, 1999 kb/s, 29.92 fps, 29.92 tbr, 1k tbn
File 'outputRTMP.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #1:1 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0000018c0d1321c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000018c0d1321c0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0000018c0d1321c0] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, flv, to 'outputRTMP.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : session
    encoder         : Lavf58.3.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.9.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.9.100 libmp3lame
Past duration 0.931999 too large
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 92 packets
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 2904 packets
Past duration 0.671654 too large
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0da140] concealing 4160 DC, 4160 AC, 4160 MV errors in I frame
Past duration 0.991997 too large
Past duration 0.791328 too large     256kB time=00:00:05.12 bitrate= 409.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=12 speed=4.14x
Past duration 0.969994 too large
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 573 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8a80] concealing 2468 DC, 2468 AC, 2468 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.670326 too large
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 25 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8a80] concealing 6479 DC, 6479 AC, 6479 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.961327 too large     512kB time=00:00:11.10 bitrate= 377.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=16 speed=1.57x
Past duration 0.689323 too large
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 620 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0da140] negative number of zero coeffs at 33 32
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0da140] error while decoding MB 33 32
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0da140] concealing 4336 DC, 4336 AC, 4336 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.790321 too large
Past duration 0.910332 too large     768kB time=00:00:12.23 bitrate= 514.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=18 speed=1.62x
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 24 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0da140] corrupted macroblock 22 25 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0da140] error while decoding MB 22 25
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0da140] concealing 5151 DC, 5151 AC, 5151 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.924324 too large    1024kB time=00:00:17.03 bitrate= 492.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=19 speed= 1.3x
Past duration 0.656654 too large
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 516 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0daf00] Invalid level prefix
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0daf00] error while decoding MB 0 36
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0daf00] concealing 3889 DC, 3889 AC, 3889 MV errors in P frame
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 132 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8a80] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8a80] error while decoding MB 55 26
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8a80] concealing 5034 DC, 5034 AC, 5034 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d9cc0] concealing 2621 DC, 2621 AC, 2621 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.935661 too large
Past duration 0.878319 too large
Past duration 0.929329 too large    1280kB time=00:00:18.32 bitrate= 572.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=22 speed=1.27x
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 560 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] Invalid level prefix
Past duration 0.661659 too large
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] error while decoding MB 91 24
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] concealing 5214 DC, 5214 AC, 5214 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.823662 too large
Past duration 0.864662 too large
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 29 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] corrupted macroblock 42 3 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] error while decoding MB 42 3
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] concealing 7760 DC, 7760 AC, 7760 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.780663 too large    1792kB time=00:00:19.50 bitrate= 752.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=24 speed=1.27x
Past duration 0.900322 too large
Past duration 0.990990 too large
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 565 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] corrupted macroblock 83 27 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] Past duration 0.862999 too large
error while decoding MB 83 27
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] concealing 4866 DC, 4866 AC, 4866 MV errors in P frame
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 7 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8f00] top block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8f00] error while decoding MB 79 16
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8f00] concealing 2661 DC, 2661 AC, 2661 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.907997 too large
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet= 816.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=28 speed=1.29x
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 19 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d9cc0] corrupted macroblock 88 59 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d9cc0] error while decoding MB 88 59
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d9cc0] concealing 1041 DC, 1041 AC, 1041 MV errors in P frame
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 6 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] out of range intra chroma pred mode
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] error while decoding MB 118 6
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] concealing 3320 DC, 3320 AC, 3320 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.845665 too large    2304kB time=00:00:20.72 bitrate= 910.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=29 speed=1.23x
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 574 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] negative number of zero coeffs at 39 26
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] error while decoding MB 39 26
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] concealing 5050 DC, 5050 AC, 5050 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.950996 too large
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 37 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] corrupted macroblock 48 37 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] error while decoding MB 48 37
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8140] concealing 3721 DC, 3721 AC, 3721 MV errors in P frame
Past duration 0.789330 too large    2816kB time=00:00:22.02 bitrate=1047.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=33 speed=1.23x
Past duration 0.848320 too large
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 581 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8f00] corrupted macroblock 13 10 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8f00] error while decoding MB 13 10
Past duration 0.875664 too large
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8f00] concealing 6952 DC, 6952 AC, 6952 MV errors in P frame
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] max delay reached. need to consume packet=1181.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=35 speed=1.25x
[rtsp @ 0000018c0ccba6c0] RTP: missed 6 packets
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8f00] corrupted macroblock 72 37 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8f00] error while decoding MB 72 37
[h264 @ 0000018c0d0d8f00] concealing 3675 DC, 3675 AC, 3675 MV errors in P frame
frame=  101 fps=5.3 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4095kB time=00:00:23.67 bitrate=1417.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=37 speed=1.25x
video:3739kB audio:340kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.405426%
[libx264 @ 0000018c0d1321c0] frame I:1     Avg QP:20.00  size:178581
[libx264 @ 0000018c0d1321c0] frame P:100   Avg QP:20.42  size: 36495
[libx264 @ 0000018c0d1321c0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000018c0d1321c0] mb P  I16..4: 11.8%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 31.7%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:56.5%
[libx264 @ 0000018c0d1321c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 26.5% 36.0% 9.2% inter: 15.0% 18.5% 3.4%
[libx264 @ 0000018c0d1321c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 44% 39% 10%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000018c0d1321c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 36% 36% 21%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000018c0d1321c0] kb/s:1383.65
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

So If you have some ideas for me it will help. Thank you

Comment: Instead of transcoding, just copy the video and audio streams into the mp4 container and see if that makes a difference. Any video converting can be done afterwards as it will add a lot of overhead.

Comment: Here the output is mp4 but in the futur it will be rtmp. So copy to rtmp is OK ??

Comment: From what I can gather from your OP is you want to mux them, but from the outputs you're transcoding them too. Muxing takes little to no overhead, but transcoding/converting the videos takes a lot. I would mux them into a single file and transcode/convert them afterwards, if needed. You would find then you will not get as much packet loss.